# Spree admin authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan, spree

What does the line `authorize! :admin, model` mean in the following code? I couldn't find the `:admin` action anywhere in the code. Is this something similar to `:manage` option?

```
spree_auth-1.0.3/app/controllers/spree/admin/admin_controller_decorator.rb:

require File.expand_path('../../base_controller_decorator', __FILE__)
Spree::Admin::BaseController.class_eval do
  before_filter :authorize_admin

  def authorize_admin
    begin
      model = model_class
    rescue
      model = Object
    end
    authorize! :admin, model
    authorize! params[:action].to_sym, model
  end

  protected
    def model_class
      "Spree::#{controller_name.classify}".constantize
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method comes from the [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem. It's used to ensure that the `current_user` is authorized to perform the actions within any controller that inherits from `Spree::Admin::BaseController.`